# What type of plant is Léon's plant?

Tags: leon-the-professional

I would like to know what type of plant Léon's plant is in *Léon: The Professional*. (Related: [Question about what the story of Léon's plant is](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/30902).)

Comment: Voting to reopen. The community has [changed its stance on "trivia" questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006), and the ["trivia" close reason doesn’t apply anymore](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1006). (Links lead to the relevant [meta] posts.)

Comment: Relevant meta post about this question: [Requesting the reopening of "What type of plant is Léon's plant?"](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4964/1006)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an Aglaonema, or [Chinese evergreen](https://econutplants.com/plants/why-chinese-evergreen-plants-are-great-idea-top-8-reasons). Common indoor plant. Unfortunately, Mathilda planting it outside would kill it. These are tropical plants that don't hold up to the cold of NY where it is set. Of course, the movie is filmed mostly in Paris, which rarely gets below freezing.

Comment: Then it would be at the end be dead... like Leon! :) thx!